# Passing custom swift object to javascript methods as input

Tags: ios, swift, javascriptcore

I'm using javascriptcore framework to interact with the JS file functions.
I have the object in the following type

```
class Test: NSObject {

var testId: NSNumber?
var testIndex: Int?
var testDate: NSDate?
var title: String?
var status: String?
}
```

I'm creating the array of object and passing as input to javascript method like below

```
var testArray = [Test]()
for i in 0 ..< 4 {
let test = Test()
test.testId = i * 3
test.testIndex = i
test.testDate = NSDate()
test.title = "Test \(i)"
test.status = "waiting"
testArray.append(test)
}
```

I have to pass this array to method to JS, Please let me know how to pass it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass the attributes to JS as described here:
http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/

**The blocks-way**

Couldn't test the code without Mac now, but is maybe working:

```
let testArrayCount: @convention(block) Void -> String = {
  return testArray.count
}

let transferTest: @convention(block) String -> (String, String, String, String, String) = {
  i in
  return ( String(testArray[i].0),String(testArray[i].1),String(testArray[i].2),testArray[i].3,testArray[i].4 )
}

context.setObject(unsafeBitCast(testArrayCount, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "testArrayCount")
context.setObject(unsafeBitCast(transferTest, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "transferTest")
```

Now you can read the array in your JS-code (this is Pseudocode now):

```
var jsTestArray;
for ( i=0, i<testArrayCount(), i++ ) {
  jsTestArray.append( transferTest(i) );
}
```

After loading object after object into your Javascript, you should be able to work with the array. If you don't want to work with strings only you may have to cast the things back (but as JS noob I don't wheather it's necessary)

**Using JSExport Protocol**

You can try it also the other way, described on http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/ .

Hope, this answered your question?